# How to get JavaScript output in Flask

Tags: javascript, python, json, flask

```
function dragEnd(e) {
      if (activeItem !== null) {
        activeItem.initialX = activeItem.currentX;
        activeItem.initialY = activeItem.currentY;
      }

      var classname = activeItem.className;

      if (classname == "item one") {
        console.log(activeItem.initialX + 20);
        console.log(activeItem.initialY + 20);
        active = false;
        activeItem = null;
      }
      else if(classname == "item two"){
        console.log(activeItem.initialX + 20);
        console.log(activeItem.initialY + 60);
        active = false;
        activeItem = null;
      }
```

How to get the values that console.log elements in Flask. If should I convert JSON element then get, help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about is sending data from JavaScript to a Flask API, correct me if I am wrong.

For that purpose, you can store your data into a variable and send it through a POST or GET request using **axios**. Read about axios [here](https://axios-http.com/docs/intro).

```js
axios.get("https://flask-app-url.com/endpoint?mydata=SOME_VALUE")
```

Since you mentioned JSON, I should let you know that it recommended to use the POST method and send JSON.

You then have to receive the data in Flask itself, for which you can create a simple endpoint. For example if you're using the GET method, do something like:

```py
data = request.args.get('mydata')
```

You get the idea. For POST it would be something like `request.form["mydata"]` with formdata type.